# UDP - lost data during microbursts

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-asio

The code below runs great (ie. doesn't drop messages) 99.9 of the time. But when there's a microburst of datagrams coming in at the rate of 2-3 microseconds between datagrams, then I experience data loss. The boost notify_one() member call requires 5 to 10 microseconds to complete, so that by itself is the key bottleneck under these conditions. Any suggestions on how to improve performance?

Receiver/"producer" code thread:

```
if (bytes_recvd > 0) {
    InQ.mut.lock();
    string t;
    t.append(data_, bytes_recvd);
    InQ.msg_queue.push(t);    // < 1 microsecs
    InQ.mut.unlock();
    InQ.cond.notify_one();    // 5 - 10 microsecs
}
```

Consumer code thread:

```
//snip......
std::string s;
while (1) {
    InQ.mut.lock();
    if (!InQ.msg_queue.empty()) {
        s.clear();
        s = InQ.msg_queue.front();
        InQ.msg_queue.pop();
    }
    InQ.mut.unlock();
    if (s.length()) {
        processDatagram((char *)s.c_str(), s.length());
        s.clear();
    }
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(InQ.mut);
    InQ.cond.wait(lock);
}
```

Comment: In linux you can increase the kernel buffer for packets per socket so you don't lose them, i guess you can do that on windows as well.

Comment: UDP as a standard does not guarantee delivery.  If you want guaranteed delivery, use TCP/IP.

Comment: just because you use UDP it doesn't mean that you happily lose packets.

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
if (!InQ.msg_queue.empty()) {
```

to

```
while (!InQ.msg_queue.empty()) {
```

That way packets don't have to wake the thread to get processed, if the thread is already awake and busy, it will see the new packet before sleeping.

Ok, it's not quite that simple, because you need to release the lock between packets, but the idea will work -- before sleeping, check whether the queue is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you're losing data try increasing your socket buffer read size.  If you're using boost::asio, look into this option:  `boost::asio::socket_base::receiver_buffer_size`.  Generally for our high throughput UDP applications we set the socket buffer size to 1MB (more in some cases).

Also, make sure that the buffers you're using in your receive calls are not too large, they should only be large enough to handle your maximum expected datagram size (which is obviously implementation dependent).

Answer (score 1):

Your obvious clog is in the conditioning.
Your main hope would be in using a lockless Q implementation. This is probably an obvious statement to you. 
The only way to really get the lockless q to work for you, of course, is if you have multicores and don't mind dedicating on to the consuming task.

Answer (score 0):

Some general suggestions:

- Increase socket receive buffer size.
- Read all available datagrams, then pass them all on for processing.
- Avoid data copying, pass pointers around.
- Reduce lock scope to absolute minimum, say, only push/pop a pointer onto/off the queue under that mutex.
- If all above fails you, look into lock-free data structures to pass data around.

Hope this helps.

Comment: All these suggestions make me hopeful. But one question is since I'm using boost's async_receive_from() how do I use it to read all available datagrams?

Comment: I don't know `asio` that well. In general though, you'd set the socket to non-blocking and read until you get `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: I'll look into if/how that can be accomplished using asio and async_receive_from().

Comment: Doing more research, looks like there's was a non-blocking issue in the asio  libraries that has been fixed in 1.47, so I'm in the process of switching from 1.46 to 1.47 and will see if the async_receive_from() can be made to not block.